# Delay adding images to div in for loop

Tags: jquery, image, delay

I want to add some time between adding the images to the  element. This is my code :

```
    <script>
        var aantalkeergeklikt = 0;
        var uniekeid = 0;
        var pictures = ["../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/bom.png", "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/green.png", "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/red.png", "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/yellow.png", "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/orange.png", "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/purple.png", "../Spel in jQuery/img/bubbles/blue.png"];
        var size = pictures.length

        for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            uniekeid = uniekeid + 1;
            var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())

            var item = $("<img src='" + pictures[x] + "' alt='" + uniekeid + "' />").hide().delay("slow").fadeIn();
            $('#depionnen').append(item);
            console.log(item.alt);
        }

    </script>
```

At this point the delay is applied after adding all the images.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use a setTimeout to delay a for loop.

```
var i = 1;                     //  set your counter to 1

function myLoop () {           //  create a loop function
   setTimeout(function () {    //  call a 3s setTimeout when the loop is called
      alert('hello');          //  your code here
      i++;                     //  increment the counter
      if (i < 10) {            //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
         myLoop();             //  ..  again which will trigger another 
      }                        //  ..  setTimeout()
   }, 3000)
}

myLoop();                      //  start the loop
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3583740/2932698)

So in your example it would be something like this:

```
var i = 1;                     

function myLoop () {           
   setTimeout(function () {    
      uniekeid = uniekeid + 1;
      var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
      var item = $("<img src='" + pictures[x] + "' alt='" + uniekeid + "' />").hide().delay("slow").fadeIn();
      $('#depionnen').append(item);
      console.log(item.alt);   

      i++;                     
      if (i < 20) {             
         myLoop();             
      }                        
   }, 3000)
}

myLoop();
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer so other people know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general solution to this type of problem:

```
function nextPic() {
  if(pictures.length) {
    var item = $('<img src="' + pictures.shift() + '">')
               .hide()
               .delay('slow')
               .fadeIn(nextPic);

    $('#depionnen').append(item);
  }
} //nextPic

nextPic();
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g4kz72bp/1)

Comment: That is not what he was asking for. He was asking for a delay. Not effects

Comment: @BramDriesen, moving **slow** from `delay` to `fadeIn` should accomplish the same thing.  Op can respond if this doesn't meet his requirements.

Comment: Not really. Take this for example.  A page loading 10K pictures with a for loop all at once but with effects !== loading with delay. It might look the same. But it's something different.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right!  I've updated my answer.

Comment: One question, so many different answers ;) It's just how you read it

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.delay()` only delays effects on the same element. 
Try using `setTimeout()` instead, which would look something like this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    uniekeid = uniekeid + 1;
    var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())

    var item = $("<img src='" + pictures[x] + "' alt='" + uniekeid + "' />").hide();
    $('#depionnen').append(item);

    setTimeout( function(item){ item.fadeIn(); }, i*600, item);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5eygxdv1/